# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i write some code that returns two outputs. The error appears. What is the main problem of my code???????

I use from python3.x - beautifulsoup4-4.6.3

```
import codecs
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

for i in range(3): #electronic

my_url = "https://www.bamilo.com/mobile_phones/?facet_is_mpg_child=0&viewType=gridView&page="

uClient = uReq(my_url + str(i))

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div" , {"class" : "sku -gallery" })

filename = "mobile.csv"
f = codecs.open(filename, "a" , "utf-8-sig")
headers = "name, Brand, price_one, price_two, ranking\n"
f.write(headers)


for container in containers:

    name = container.img["alt"]

    title_container = container.findAll("span", {"class" : "brand"})

    Brand = title_container[0].text

    price = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "price"} )

    price_one = price[0].text.strip()

    price_old = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "price -old "})
    price_two = 0
    if len(price_old) > 0:
        price_two = price_old[0].text.strip()

    rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"})
    if len(rank) > 0:
        ranking = rank[0].text.strip()

    print("name " + name)
    print("Brand "+ Brand)
    print("price_one " + price_one)
    print("price_two {}".format(price_two))
    print("ranking " + ranking)

    f.write(name + "," + Brand.replace(",", "|") + "," + price_one.replace(",", "") + "," + price_two.replace(",", "") + "," + ranking + "\n")

f.close()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   name Galaxy J7 Pro SM-J730FD Dual 64GB Gold
>     File "C:/Users/...../.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 53, in 
>   Brand Samsung 
>       f.write(name + "," + Brand.replace(",", "|") + "," + price_one.replace(",", "") + "," + price_two.replace(",", "") + "," + ranking + "\n")
>   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
>   price_one 32,050,000ریال
>   price_two 0
>   ranking 1

Error :::::

```
f.write(name + "," + Brand.replace(",", "|") + "," + 
price_one.replace(",", "") + "," + price_two.replace(",", "") + "," + 
ranking + "\n")

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

What changes should be applied? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because of this line `price_two = 0` if the condition you set is not met then the value of `price_two` is a integer. And you cannot use `str.replace` on it.

to fix problem replace

```
price_two = 0
```

to

```
price_two = '0'  #To string
```